# Error trying to load / parse XML file with DocumentBuilder

Tags: katalon-studio

I'm trying to load an XML file and have started to get an error after updating Katalon from 6.1.5 to 6.2.

Error in question:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/elementtraversal

Error is thrown when trying to parse the file.

Even though the error is pretty clear that the class is not recognized / found; I ruled out malformed XML file.

```java
File docXmlFile = new File("C:\\data", "info.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentFactoryBuilder.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(docXmlFile); // error is thrown here!
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement(); // this line isn't reached
```

Trying to figure out what had changed as this code has been working for quite a while.

If i had to guess it's probably some dependency or missing JAR file, not sure which one and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forum.katalon.com/t/keyword-runfeaturefile-was-failed-root-cause-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-boolean/17269/22) on Katalon forum, this is a known issue that has been fixed in version **6.2.1.**

Comment: You are correct. 
I couldn't wait for 6.2.1 (which is now out) and eventually created a simple parser to solve my problem.